# How to open different URLs by checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

This is my HTML and JavaScript code

```
<input type="text" id="text" /> 
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://example.com/' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />
```

If you input `anytext` in the form box and click on the **Submit** button, it will open `http://example.com/anytext`. 
I want to add three checkbox named `page1` `page2` and `page3` under the form. If I click on the checkbox `page1` and click on submit button, it will open `http://example.com/page1/anytext`

How can I do it?

Comment: I would suggest radio buttons over checkboxes. Checkboxes might lead you to something like `http://example.com/page1/page2/page3/anytext` which is not desired I assume.

Comment: @rndus2r how can I add radio buttons?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create  a function that processes the value of the checkboxes and returns the string that you need to insert into the `window.open` call. Something like this:

```
onClick="javascript: window.open('http://example.com/' +getRadioValue() + document.getElementById('text').value);"
```

Also, note that the snippet won't redirect you when you click submit due to the sandbox restrictions on it, but you can see the error in browser console and the page the code attempts to redirect you to.

```js
function getRadioValue () {
  var cb1 = document.getElementById("cb1");
  var cb2 = document.getElementById("cb2");
  var cb3 = document.getElementById("cb3");
  
  if(cb1.checked) {
    return "Page 1/";
  } else if(cb2.checked) {
    return "Page 2/";
  } else if(cb3.checked) {
    return "Page 3/";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" />
<br/>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Page 1" id="cb1" />
Page 1
</label>
<br/>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Page 2" id="cb2" />
Page 2
</label>
<br/>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Page 3" id="cb3" />
Page 3
</label>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://example.com/' +getRadioValue() + document.getElementById('text').value);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to do by jquery. This is what I think you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="text" /><br />
    page1<input type="checkbox" id="page1" value="page1" />&nbsp;
    page2<input type="checkbox" id="page2" value="page2" />&nbsp;
    page3<input type="checkbox" id="page3" value="page3" />&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" /><br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready()
        {
            //Event handler fro button click
            $('#btn').click(function ()

                {
                var text = $('#text').val();
                if($('#page1').is(':checked'))
                {
                    window.open('http://example.com/' + $('#page1').val() + '/' + text);
                }
                else if($('#page2').is(':checked'))
                {
                    window.open('http://example.com/' + $('#page2').val() + '/' + text);
                }
                else if($('#page3').is(':checked'))
                {
                    window.open('http://example.com/' + $('#page3').val() + '/' + text);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Please select a checkbox');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```